# How to change Firefox add-on owner?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, amo

### What happened

I created a small add-on and I signed it with `jpm sign` so I can install it on a few computers. Being my first add-on I created a throwaway account on [Firefox Addons](http://addons.mozilla.org) to see how things go. After my success I created my main account and deleted the throwaway one, but when I tried to sign my add-on with the new credentials, I got this:

> JPM [error] Server response: You do not own this addon. ( status: 403 )
> JPM [info] FAIL

### Problem

I tried to delete my Add-on account but it said I can't while I have add-ons under my account, **but it let me delete my Firefox account**. When I realised the jpm error I tried to log back to Firefox Add-ons which doesn't recognise me because my Firefox account is deleted (Seriously? How did they designed this system?) so now I only have my source code which doesn't let me sign with different credentials.

### Question

Is there a way to re-sign my add-on with the new credentials, without creating a new add-on? Can I change add-on ownership? How can I delete my add-on if I can't log in to my account?

Comment: The easiest thing to do (given that you say *you* have installed this only "on a few computers") is probably what @Noitidart says in the last line of his answer. Just give the add-on a new ID. Then the system thinks it is a completely new add-on and you can move forward from there. If you had an installed base of users, then you would not want to do that, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to email amo-editors@mozilla.org (they'll loop in amo-admins@mozilla.org )and they'll help you access your old account. You'll have to prove somehow it was you. Once on the old account you have to delete the old addon listing, so it frees up the addon id.

The only way you can do this without having to email, is by using a new id for your addon.

Comment: I came to this conclusion too, but does this really mean that there is no way to change the author?